# PHP - max scripts/tasks at same time

Tags: php, multithreading, plesk

I wrote a big product importer script that must be started multiple times so it takes advantage of multiple cores.

If I start the script in plesk via scheduled tasks 8 times it is only running five scripts at the same time:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    4994 root      20   0 2956004 1.573g  16212 R  74.5  6.6  45:52.21 php
     1636 root      20   0 2976000 1.592g  16224 R  72.8  6.6  77:04.52 php
     4338 root      20   0 2971744 1.588g  16468 R  72.2  6.6  49:11.41 php
     4919 root      20   0 2985488 1.597g  16216 R  69.8  6.7  45:31.94 php
     5907 root      20   0 2958256 1.576g  16484 R  69.8  6.6  45:04.00 php
```

Where and how is it possible to define the max number of scripts running by a user?

Currently running PHP 7.2.9 on a 12 core machine.

Just saw that the tasks weren't started:

```
| 2018-08-22 09:26:43 | 181 | scheduler-run-task                       | started     |               0 | ea66c06c1e1c05fa9f1aa39d98dc5bc1 | queue          | NULL           |         100 |             0 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |  4330 | NULL       |
| 2018-08-22 09:29:25 | 182 | scheduler-run-task                       | started     |               0 | ea66c06c1e1c05fa9f1aa39d98dc5bc1 | queue          | NULL           |         100 |             0 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |  4911 | NULL       |
| 2018-08-22 09:29:46 | 183 | scheduler-run-task                       | started     |               0 | ea66c06c1e1c05fa9f1aa39d98dc5bc1 | queue          | NULL           |         100 |             0 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |  4986 | NULL       |
| 2018-08-22 09:32:59 | 185 | scheduler-run-task                       | started     |               0 | ea66c06c1e1c05fa9f1aa39d98dc5bc1 | queue          | NULL           |         100 |             0 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 26735 | NULL       |
| 2018-08-22 09:34:30 | 186 | scheduler-run-task                       | started     |               0 | ea66c06c1e1c05fa9f1aa39d98dc5bc1 | queue          | NULL           |         100 |             0 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 | 31270 | NULL       |
| 2018-08-22 09:34:43 | 187 | scheduler-run-task                       | not_started |               0 | ea66c06c1e1c05fa9f1aa39d98dc5bc1 | queue          | NULL           |         100 |             0 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |     0 | NULL       |
| 2018-08-22 10:21:06 | 188 | scheduler-run-task                       | not_started |               0 | ea66c06c1e1c05fa9f1aa39d98dc5bc1 | queue          | NULL           |         100 |             0 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |     0 | NUL
```

So only the 5 tasks I can see with "top" are running - can I force the start of these other tasks?

Thanks a lot for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass different parameters at the end of file like ./schedule.php 10013 
Or
Main scheduler script call to other script using the exec command  like that exec(./scheduleOne.php 11014) to possible the multiple request.